# Runtime linker ignores RPATH in executable on solaris

Tags: linker, runtime, shared-libraries, solaris, search-path

I'm trying to compile [samtools](http://samtools.sourceforge.net/) on a Solaris server where I do not have root. Samtools depends on zlib. The system zlib on this machine is not compiled with large file support, so compiling samtools against this version has the expected effect: samtools only handle small files. I need it to be able to handle large files. Luckily, there is a version of zlib compiled by the admin in /usr/local/apps/zlib-1.2.5/ with large file support. I can compile against this by adding `-R /usr/local/apps/zlib-1.2.5/lib` to CFLAGS, but this seems not to work. The symptoms are as follows:

When I try to run samtools, it crashes with this error:

```
ld.so.1: samtools: fatal: relocation error: file samtools: symbol gzopen64: referenced symbol not found
```

If I add `/usr/local/apps/zlib-1.2.5/` to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then samtools works fine.

Analyzing samtools with ldd and readelf yields the following:

```
$ ldd -r samtools
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /usr/lib/libsocket.so.1
        libresolv.so.2 =>        /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2
        libm.so.2 =>     /usr/lib/libm.so.2
        libcurses.so.1 =>        /usr/lib/libcurses.so.1
        libz.so =>       /usr/lib/libz.so
        libc.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/libc.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /usr/lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/libmd.so.1
        libscf.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/libscf.so.1
        libdoor.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/libdoor.so.1
        libuutil.so.1 =>         /usr/lib/libuutil.so.1
        libgen.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/libgen.so.1
        symbol not found: gzopen64              (samtools)

$ ldd -s samtools

   ...(snip)...

   find object=libz.so; required by samtools
    search path=/usr/lib:/usr/openwin/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/local/lib  (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
    trying path=/usr/lib/libz.so
        libz.so =>       /usr/lib/libz.so

   ...(snip)...

$ readelf -d samtools | grep RPATH
 0x0000000f (RPATH)                      Library rpath: [/usr/local/apps/zlib-1.2.5/lib:/usr/local/apps/gcc-4.5.1/lib]
```

So `/usr/local/apps/zlib-1.2.5/lib` is clearly in the binary's RPATH, which I understand is supposed to be searched at runtime for shared libraries. However, `ldd -s` shows that this directory is never searched. Adding this path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and re-running the ldd commands has the expected effect: the directory is searched and the correct version of libz is found.

So how can I force samtools to search in `/usr/local/apps/zlib-1.2.5/lib` at runtime without using LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

---

Edit: The documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-1984/chapter2-84569/index.html) would seem to indicate that the `-R` option is the correct thing to do. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm by no means a Solaris expert, but this line:

```
find object=libz.so; required by samtools
 search path=/usr/lib:/usr/openwin/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/local/lib  (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
```

seems to indicate to me that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is already set, and the `/usr/lib` path in it is taking precedence over any runtime linker paths. Can you unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH if it is in fact present and see if that resolves it?

Comment: Gah! You're right! But none of my init files are setting it, so I have no idea how it is being set. Nevertheless, unsetting it makes things work. Seems like a misconfigured server. I'll unset it in my shell init files and email the sysadmin.

Comment: Now that I've calmed down a little, I'd like to add "thank you."